# running ocaml on Mac OS X gives bus error

Tags: macos, installation, ocaml

I've just installed Ocaml on Mac OS X, and when I run the ocaml program I get a "Bus Error" with no other clues to what might be going on.  Can anyone offer suggestions on where to go from here?

EDIT:

I installed via the package:

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/distrib/ocaml-3.10/ocaml-3.10.2-ppc.dmg

(I have an iBook G4, so PPC is appropriate)

To run ocaml, I just typed:

```
ocaml
```

in a terminal window

I also tried

```
/usr/local/bin/ocaml
```

and running from an xterm window.  All three give:

```
Bus Error
```

I have Xcode and X11 installed as the README requires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I was installing a version of OCaml built for Mac OS X 10.5.x (Leopard) on my machine running 10.4.x (Tiger).  One would think it would be easy for the installer to catch this, but alas...

Answer (score 1):

Did you install it from macports?  It's working fine for me.  Can you describe some more details about your installation?  Perhaps what you're doing to get the error?